Flutter Google Map works on Android version but not on iPhone version
I use the flutter application programming language
I created a page containing Google Maps through which the user specifies his location to save the address and location data in his account when creating the account
When running the version on Android, it works well
But when running the version on iPhone, the map does not appear
I put all the required permissions
And I modified the AppDelegate.swift file and added the api key to the file
However, it did not work
Xcode version 16
IOS 18
dart 3.5.4
flutter 3.22
`

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => OrderTrackingPageState();
}

class OrderTrackingPageState extends State<MapScreen> {
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  LocationData? currentLocation;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();

    if (currentLocation != null) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        sourceLocation =
            LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!);
        latitude = currentLocation!.latitude;
        longitude = currentLocation!.longitude;
      });
    }
  }

  LatLng? sourceLocation;
  String _selectedAddress = '';
  String City = '';
  String Country = '';
  String Postalcode = '';
  String State = '';
  String Address = '';

  void _handleMapLongPress(LatLng position) async {
    String apiKey = 'AIz***********************************';
    String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$apiKey';

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data['status'] == 'OK') {
        String formattedAddress = data['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
        List<String> addressParts = formattedAddress.split(', ');
        String country = addressParts.last;
        String city = addressParts[addressParts.length - 2];
        String street =
            addressParts.sublist(0, addressParts.length - 2).join(', ');

        setState(() {
          Address = street;
          City = city;
          Country = country;
        });

        List<dynamic> addressComponents =
            data['results'][0]['address_components'];
        String postalCode = '';
        String state = '';

        for (var component in addressComponents) {
          List<dynamic> types = component['types'];
          if (types.contains('postal_code')) {
            postalCode = component['long_name'];
            setState(() {
              Postalcode = postalCode;
            });
          } else if (types.contains('administrative_area_level_1')) {
            state = component['long_name'];
            setState(() {
              State = state;
            });
          }
        }

        setState(() {
          _selectedAddress = '''
$country, $city,
$street
Postal Code: $postalCode
State: $state
''';
        });
      }
    }
  }

  void _showAddressPopup() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Add Address'),
          content: TextField(
            controller: addressController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: _selectedAddress,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String address = addressController.text;
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      sourceLocation =
          LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!, currentLocation!.longitude!);
    });

    String apiKey = 'AIz***********************************';
    String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${currentLocation!.latitude},${currentLocation!.longitude}&key=$apiKey';

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data['status'] == 'OK') {
        String formattedAddress = data['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
        List<String> addressParts = formattedAddress.split(', ');
        String country = addressParts.last;
        String city = addressParts[addressParts.length - 2];
        String street =
            addressParts.sublist(0, addressParts.length - 2).join(', ');

        setState(() {
          Address = street;
          City = city;
          Country = country;
        });

        List<dynamic> addressComponents =
            data['results'][0]['address_components'];
        String postalCode = '';
        String state = '';

        for (var component in addressComponents) {
          List<dynamic> types = component['types'];
          if (types.contains('postal_code')) {
            postalCode = component['long_name'];
            setState(() {
              Postalcode = postalCode;
            });
          } else if (types.contains('administrative_area_level_1')) {
            state = component['long_name'];
            setState(() {
              State = state;
            });
          }
        }

        setState(() {
          _selectedAddress = '''
$country, $city,
$street
Postal Code: $postalCode
State: $state
''';
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> animateToCurrentLocation() async {
    if (currentLocation != null) {
      final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
      controller.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
              currentLocation!.latitude!,
              currentLocation!.longitude!,
            ),
            zoom: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: MYTHEME.APPBAR_COLOR,
        title: const Text('تحديد الموقع الحالي'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: MYTHEME.APPBAR_COLOR,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: const Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '1. تحديد العنوان',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: MYTHEME.MAIN_COLOR),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            'في التقدم',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: MYTHEME.MAIN_COLOR),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '2. إدخال البيانات',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            'في التقدم',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    onLongPress: _handleMapLongPress,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target:
                          sourceLocation ?? const LatLng(24.774265, 46.738586),
                      zoom: 13.5,
                    ),
                    markers: {
                      Marker(
                        markerId: const MarkerId("currentLocation"),
                        position: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                            currentLocation!.longitude!),
                        infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                          title: 'موقعك الحالي',
                        ),
                      ),
                    },
                    onMapCreated: (mapController) {
                      _controller.complete(mapController);
                    },
                    polylines: {
                      Polyline(
                        polylineId: const PolylineId("route"),
                        points: polylineCoordinates,
                        color: const Color(0xFF7B61FF),
                        width: 6,
                      ),
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                if (_selectedAddress.isNotEmpty)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(_selectedAddress),
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 180,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: MYTHEME.MAIN_COLOR),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => CreateAccount(
                                      city: City,
                                      country: Country,
                                      postalcode: Postalcode,
                                      state: State,
                                      address: Address,
                                    )));
                      },
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                            Text(
                              'التالي',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              ],
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          animateToCurrentLocation();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.maps_home_work_outlined),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Question is not a question
